# Adding Afinn Score to List of Tweets

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a basic sentiment analysis project using afinn and twitter data.  My goal is to end up with a dataframe that displays the individual tweets, dates, retweets, favorites, and afinn scores.

Here is my code:

```
import sklearn as sk
import pandas as pd
import got3
tweetCriteria = got3.manager.TweetCriteria() 
tweetCriteria.setQuerySearch("Kentucky Derby")
tweetCriteria.setSince("2016-04-01") 
tweetCriteria.setUntil("2016-05-30") 
tweetCriteria.setMaxTweets(25)

KYDerby_tweets = got3.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)

from afinn import Afinn
afinn = Afinn()

for x in KYDerby_tweets:
    afinn.score

AF = afinn.score

for x in KYDerby_tweets:
    print(x.text)
    print(x.date)
    print(x.retweets)
    print(x.favorites)
    print(AF)
    print("*"*50)
```

Everything prints out fine EXCEPT for the afinn score.  In its place, I am getting the following error: >

So the first tweet in the list looks like this:

NBO: Kentucky Derby - Bourbon Barrel Edition http:// ift.tt/1pySg8M #Beer
2016-05-29 19:29:40
0
3
>

---

Sorry for the newbie question, but can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with the afinn part of my code?  Thanks!

Comment: The last part of my message didn't appear the way I wanted it to.  The error I am getting is this:  bound method Afinn.score_with_pattern of <afinn.afinn.Afinn object at 0x00000000098F3A58

Answer (score 0):

`Afinn.score` is a method, - not an attribute. You need to call the method with the text you want to have scored. I think something like `AF = afinn.score(x.text)` should work. You need to have that line of code within a loop when you want to have multiple tweets scored.

"bound method" means that the value of AF is the function itself (a reference to the function), - not the value returned from the function.